# Unmet dependencies installing teamviewer

Tags: dependencies

I was trying to install teamviewer on Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS. Now I am facing following error:

```
 *apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreetype6:i386 : Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installed
 teamviewer:i386 : Depends: libqt5gui5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5widgets5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5qml5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5quick5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5dbus5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5webkit5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: libqt5x11extras5:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installed or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: qml-module-qtquick2:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installable or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installable or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: qml-module-qtquick-dialogs:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installable or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: qml-module-qtquick-window2:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installable or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
                   Depends: qml-module-qtquick-layouts:i386 (>= 5.5) but it is not installable or
                            qt56-teamviewer:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.*
```

Please suggest!

Comment: Removed teamviewer. Following is the new situation: sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreetype6:i386 : Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: I guess it is due to version mismatch. I have x86_64

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 is dead, meaning EOL.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 first because 14.04 is no longer supported.

Comment: how to upgrade? Will I loose the data and installed packages by upgrade?

Comment: We all have to upgrade. But, make sure to backup your home folder. Press the windows key and search for about. Then check for updates.

Comment: Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenialUpgrades  (*it's always best to follow official documentation in my opinion*).  Backup first of course, for best results 3rd party software should be removed/disabled, your system *release-upgraded* then if necessary 3rd party software re-added. You've provided little detail (desktop? server? software installed etc) but it'll take longer than re-install (which for desktop doesn't lose packages anyway in most cases) & will keep packages but depends on what packages  @VincentVictor